# Controller not executed: Error 404

Tags: php, codeigniter

I use CI v2.0.3 , xampp windows 1.7.0 , and I renamed the CI folder to "Hello"
I created a Blog.php at application/controller.

The content of Blog.php is:

```
<?php
if(!defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No Direct Script Access Allowed');

class Blog extends CI_Controller {
        function __construct()
        {
            parent::__construct();
        }

        function index()
        {
            echo "Haloo.. CI pertama";     
        }
}
```

I want to access `localhost:8080/hello/index.php/blog` or `localhost:8080/hello/index.php/Blog` but both of them still show `404 not found`.
This is what I expect instead: "Haloo.. CI pertama".

Comment: if(!!defined('BASEPATH')) is this a typo?

Comment: @radashk if I compare with CI default controller example, it seems to be a typo.

Comment: thx for correction, but still 404not found..

Comment: Does the `404` error look "flashy" or rather ugly? I'm asking because we first need to establish, whether CI is being invoked *at all*.

Comment: Maybe this is too obvious, but you DID actually place CI inside XAMPP's htdocs directory, right? With index.php at [xampp path]\htdocs\hello\index.php? Is it an Apache 404 or CI's?

Comment: @dgeare Really obvious :D I put the CI folder inside htdocs folder. And for sure the 404 is CI's not the Apache because I only get 404error on the CI project..

Comment: @phant0m I dont get what flashy / rather ugly means here..

Comment: Okay, you can just upload a screenshot of the 404 error then.

Comment: If you change CI's config/routes.php file so the default controller is blog and then just visit localhost/hello/index.php do you still get 404? or expected output

Answer (score 0):

If your CI folder is named 'Hello' then you access it like this:

```
http://localhost:8080/Hello/index.php/blog
```

Whatch out! the folder name is case sensitive so `/hello/index.php/blog` will not work

Comment: Can you access localhost ? does XAMPP show you the Hello folder there?

Comment: Did you change anything in the /config/config.php ? or a .htaccess file?

Comment: @radask yes, I can access to xampp home, there are menus of phpadmin , phpinfo etc isnt't it?

I do not change any config from config.php.. I just change the apache port to 8080, because port 80 have conflict with my SQL Server Service...

Comment: still the same, 404page not found..
Is it have some relation with the port?
Or the htaccess? I haven't modified anything..

Comment: I don't think so. You shouldn't be having a .htaccess file. Do you have one in your Hello folder? what does it contain?

Comment: Sorry, I dont have any htaccess file in hello folder..
htaccess are in application, system, etc..

Comment: That's fine.. now go to wamp in tray.. and open the apache error log and access log. What does it say on the last lines?

Comment: I fixed the problems up by re-installing xampp with the latest version , using the latest CI, and diabling the UAC on my windows 7..

Answer (score -1):

The URL you have entered isn't correct if you haven't enabled the Rewrite module for Apache. For your settings considering the folder name also try:

```
http://localhost:8080/Hello/index.php?/blog
```

**Edit:** Folder name added

Comment: Really, still 404php not found..
Can you tell me what kind of problem it is?

Comment: Can you share the physical path of CodeIgniter?

Answer (score -3):

You need to render a view in your index action.

Your views are located in application/views. So you'll have to create a file called `index.php` there in which you'll put `Hello World`. And then you'll add this to your function:

```
$this->load->view('index');
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: It is kind of frustating because I have this prob 2 days ago, smth wrong with my laptops?

Comment: @adadeh I don't think something is wrong with your setup, it must be a very dumb error that we all can't find hehe. Go read http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/urls.html maybe you'll find out...